# Dynamically update yammer Feed in Embed widget

Tags: javascript, yammer

I'm calling the Embed widget snippet from inside a Backbone app and I'd like to trigger a new feed to be pulled in depending on a dynamic group ID being passed to the widget

Currently it looks as if the Embed widget is trying to embed a new feed every time the code is called so I end up with multiple feeds on the page. I can't find any mention in the documentation of a remove or empty method on the yam.connect object

I have also tried a simple jQuery empty on the container and I think this is failing because the yam.connect object has created a data binding in memory with the instantiated embed data

```
setYammerFeed: function(feedID){
    //empty current container before embedding a new Yammer panel
    $('#embedded-feed').empty();
    console.log($('#embedded-feed'))
    if ( feedID ) {
      yam.connect.embedFeed({
        container: '#embedded-feed',
        network: 'valtech.co.uk',
        feedType: 'group',                         
        feedId: feedID,
        config: {
          use_sso: true,
          header: true,
          footer: true,
          showOpenGraphPreview: false
        }
      });
    }else{
      yam.connect.embedFeed({
        container: '#embedded-feed',
        network: 'valtech.co.uk',
        feedType: 'group',
        feedId: '4621895',
        config: {
          use_sso: true,
          header: true,
          footer: true,
          showOpenGraphPreview: false
        }
      });
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, the `yam.connect.embedFeed()` appends an iframe to the DOM element specified by the `container` field, regardless of the previously appended iframes. But you should be able to empty the container with a jQuery `empty()` call. Can you show us the code you use?